# Using "drop by", "call on" or "come round" as synonym of "make a short visit" in video game?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Is using  "drop by", "call on" or "come round" proper to a situation when I have little time for playing game so I just log in, look around at what's happening, maybe play one match and log out?

For example:

> I don't play the game regularly. I just drop by/call on/come round from time to time to see what going on.

Comment: As you are not going anywhere or actually visiting, isn't your "log in" descriptive enough?

Comment: Alone "log in" doesn't satisfy me but I can accept that, if "drop by" and others words require undertaking a physical travel to a place. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could "touch base".